# Publish Test Results Task - Can't find Karma JUnit test results file

Tags: junit, azure-devops

When I run ng test locally the file is created and I assume it is as well when the step executes in the build process... it always reports it can't be found, what is the best way to troubleshoot?

Comment: Please check if the answer below solves your problem. If not, Could you provide the detailed error message and YAML script of test task and publish task? So that we can further investigate the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue may be due to the working directory of the test task and the search folder of the publish task do not match.

The following is an example:

Here is a test task:

```
- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: custom
    customCommand: run test
    workingDir: {path A}
```

In your test configuration file, there would be a piece of script defines the path to store test results.

```
junitReporter: {
      outputDir: '../{path B}'
    },
```

If you can't find where the script is, you can infer the path based on where the local test results are stored.

And here is the Publish Test Results Task:

```
- task: PublishTestResults@2
  inputs:
    searchFolder: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/{path A}/{path B}
    testResultsFormat: JUnit
    testResultsFiles: "**/TESTS*.xml"
```

**Notice the parameter `searchFolder`. Its value should be as shown above.**

If the test results are still not found:

1. You can set the value of `testResultsFiles` to `"**"` and set the value of `searchFolder` to `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`. Then you can see if there are test files in `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`.
2. If you are using anothor task to test, maybe the test results are not in `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`. You can read the documentation for this task to see what task's default output path is.